# Xamarin Forms: ScrollView with KeyBoard

Tags: c#, xamarin, scrollview

I am on the most current version of Xamarin Forms. I have a Content Page. The Content Page has a grid that has a scrollview that has a stacklayout that contains some image and Entry inputs and some Buttons. When I touch the Entry to enter text, the keyboard covers the Buttons so I can't press the button. This isn't scrollable and I don't know why. Anybody can help me?

Here is my XAML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Spirocco.LoginPage">
<Grid>
    <ScrollView Orientation="Both" x:Name="scrollView">
        <ScrollView.Content>
            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#302138">
                <Image Source="login_logo" Margin="0,0,0,0"></Image>
                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" Margin="20,0,20,30">
                    <Label Text="ÜDVÖZÖLJÜK!" FontSize="30" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" Margin="0,15,0,0" TextColor="#302138" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
                    <Entry Text="{Binding Email}" Placeholder="E-mail" Margin="40,0,40,0" Keyboard="Email"/>
                    <Entry Text="{Binding Password}" Placeholder="Jelszó" IsPassword="True" Margin="40,0,40,0"/>
                    <Button Text="BEJELENTKEZÉS" Clicked="Login" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="#302138" Margin="40,10,40,0"/>
                    <Button Text="REGISZTRÁCIÓ" Clicked="Register" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="#302138" Margin="40,0,40,25"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView.Content>
    </ScrollView>
</Grid>
```

[Here is the solution](https://xamarinhelp.com/accommodate-on-screen-keyboard-xamarin-forms/)

Comment: What do you want to be scrollable?
Right now, everything within the grid is what you want to scroll. The elements within can overlap each other without being scrollable, because only the whole group of elements is.

Comment: I want to be scrollable all page. When I try to input my password I cant touch Login button because the keyboard covered it. I want to scroll down all content and able to touch the login button. Sry my English is not to good.

Comment: I think you only need to replace `<Grid>...</Grid>` with `<ContentPage.Content>...</ContentPage.Content>`. The Grid can be as big as it needs to be, no matter the viewport size. The ContentPage, however, does know what to do when the **direct** child is a ScrollView.
I can't test this, so I don't post it as answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just add this code to App.xaml.cs to make page auto-resizable

```
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;

public partial class App : Xamarin.Forms.Application
{
    public App ()
    {
        Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginTabsPage()){
        ...
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default, grid's row height value will be equals to '*' and therefore will take all the space in the screen. This is why it is not scrollable.

By the way, I don't really get why you nest in into a grid.

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
     x:Class="Spirocco.LoginPage">

<ScrollView Orientation="Both" x:Name="scrollView">
    <ScrollView.Content>
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#302138">
            <Image Source="login_logo" Margin="0,0,0,0"></Image>
            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" Margin="20,0,20,30">
                <Label Text="ÜDVÖZÖLJÜK!" FontSize="30" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" Margin="0,15,0,0" TextColor="#302138" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
                <Entry Text="{Binding Email}" Placeholder="E-mail" Margin="40,0,40,0" Keyboard="Email"/>
                <Entry Text="{Binding Password}" Placeholder="Jelszó" IsPassword="True" Margin="40,0,40,0"/>
                <Button Text="BEJELENTKEZÉS" Clicked="Login" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="#302138" Margin="40,10,40,0"/>
                <Button Text="REGISZTRÁCIÓ" Clicked="Register" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="#302138" Margin="40,0,40,25"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView.Content>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: ScrollView need a parent. Or I got Sequent Contains No Matching Element Error.

Answer (score 0):

[The Solution is Here](https://xamarinhelp.com/accommodate-on-screen-keyboard-xamarin-forms/)

It wasn't scrollable because in the stacklayout doesn't have enough content. 
I able to do this. This is not a very nice solution but works. 
I put a label width HeighRequest and same color with StackLayout and now the page is scrollable when I type my password.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Spirocco.LoginPage">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView Orientation="Both" x:Name="scrollView">
        <ScrollView.Content>
            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#302138">
                <Image Source="login_logo" Margin="0,0,0,0"></Image>
                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" Margin="20,0,20,30">
                    <Label Text="ÜDVÖZÖLJÜK!" FontSize="30" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" Margin="0,15,0,0" TextColor="#302138" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
                    <Entry Text="{Binding Email}" Placeholder="E-mail" Margin="40,0,40,0" Keyboard="Email"/>
                    <Entry Text="{Binding Password}" Placeholder="Jelszó" IsPassword="True" Margin="40,0,40,0"/>
                    <Button Text="BEJELENTKEZÉS" Clicked="Login" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="#302138" Margin="40,10,40,0"/>
                    <Button Text="REGISZTRÁCIÓ" Clicked="Register" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="#302138" Margin="40,0,40,25"/>
                </StackLayout>
                <Label BackgroundColor="#302138" HeightRequest="160"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView.Content>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: Anybody has more nicely solution?