# Scrollview is not working in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, scrollview

I have following layout in my xamarin forms application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:telerikInput="clr-namespace:Telerik.XamarinForms.Input;assembly=Telerik.XamarinForms.Input"
             xmlns:telerikPrimitives="clr-namespace:Telerik.XamarinForms.Primitives;assembly=Telerik.XamarinForms.Primitives"
             x:Class="DMGMobile.UserDetailPage">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Name="Save" Icon="settings.png" Clicked="Save"></ToolbarItem>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView 
            Orientation="Vertical" 
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <StackLayout
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Padding="10,0,10,0">

                <Label 
                    Text="Name"/>
                <telerikInput:RadEntry 
                    x:Name="User_Name"
                    BackgroundColor="White" 
                    WatermarkText="Name"
                    TextColor="Black"
                    WatermarkTextColor="#C0C0C0">
                    <telerikInput:RadEntry.Padding>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                            <On Platform="Android,UWP" Value="10,10,0,10" />
                            <On Platform="iOS" Value="10,10,0,20" />
                        </OnPlatform>
                    </telerikInput:RadEntry.Padding>
                    <telerikInput:RadEntry.BorderStyle>
                        <telerikInput:BorderStyle 
                            CornerRadius="8"
                            BorderColor="#257cc1"
                            BorderThickness="1" />
                    </telerikInput:RadEntry.BorderStyle>
                </telerikInput:RadEntry>

                <Label 
                    Text="Surname"/>
                <telerikInput:RadEntry 
                    x:Name="User_Vorname"
                    BackgroundColor="White" 
                    WatermarkText="Surname"
                    TextColor="Black"
                    WatermarkTextColor="#C0C0C0">
                    <telerikInput:RadEntry.Padding>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                            <On Platform="Android,UWP" Value="10,10,0,10" />
                            <On Platform="iOS" Value="10,10,0,20" />
                        </OnPlatform>
                    </telerikInput:RadEntry.Padding>
                    <telerikInput:RadEntry.BorderStyle>
                        <telerikInput:BorderStyle 
                        CornerRadius="8"
                        BorderColor="#257cc1"
                        BorderThickness="1" />
                    </telerikInput:RadEntry.BorderStyle>
                </telerikInput:RadEntry>

                <Label 
                    Text="Login"/>
                <telerikInput:RadEntry 
                    x:Name="User_Login"
                    BackgroundColor="White" 
                    WatermarkText="Login"
                    TextColor="Black"
                    WatermarkTextColor="#C0C0C0"
                    TextChanged="User_Login_TextChanged">
                    <telerikInput:RadEntry.Padding>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                            <On Platform="Android,UWP" Value="10,10,0,10" />
                            <On Platform="iOS" Value="10,10,0,20" />
                        </OnPlatform>
                    </telerikInput:RadEntry.Padding>
                    <telerikInput:RadEntry.BorderStyle>
                        <telerikInput:BorderStyle 
                        CornerRadius="8"
                        BorderColor="#257cc1"
                        BorderThickness="1" />
                    </telerikInput:RadEntry.BorderStyle>
                </telerikInput:RadEntry>

                <Label 
                    Text="Pass"/>
                <telerikInput:RadEntry 
                    x:Name="User_Password"
                    BackgroundColor="Transparent" 
                    WatermarkText="Pass"
                    TextColor="Black"
                    WatermarkTextColor="#C0C0C0"
                    TextChanged="User_Login_TextChanged">
                    <telerikInput:RadEntry.Padding>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                            <On Platform="Android,UWP" Value="10,10,0,10" />
                            <On Platform="iOS" Value="10,10,0,20" />
                        </OnPlatform>
                    </telerikInput:RadEntry.Padding>
                    <telerikInput:RadEntry.BorderStyle>
                        <telerikInput:BorderStyle 
                        CornerRadius="8"
                        BorderColor="#257cc1"
                        BorderThickness="1" />
                    </telerikInput:RadEntry.BorderStyle>
                </telerikInput:RadEntry>

                <telerikPrimitives:RadCheckBox 
                    x:Name="User_IsAdmin" />
                <Label 
                    Text="Is admin}"/>

            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

The problem is that ScrollView is not working. I can't even see vertical scrollbar although `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` is set to `Always`. 
The page looks nice without keyboard, but if keyboard shown then some inputs placed on the bottom of the page are hidden and I can't scroll to reach them.

Am I missing something obious here?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `HorizontalOptions` to `FillAndExpand` of the `ScrollView`?

Comment: Yes, I tried, there is no difference at all

Comment: If all the elements fit on the screen, you wouldnt see the scroll effect. Are you sure everything fits the screen? Have you tried to add more layouts ?

Comment: Here is a link you can refer to. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47693726/xamarin-forms-scrollview-with-keyboard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Android, you can add this, after LoadApplication in MainActivity:

```
Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);
```

Comment: Please explain what this does u have not added any context to your answer.