# Editor covered by xamarin forms keyboard

Tags: xamarin.forms

Hello friends how are you?
I tell you that I have a page that aims to write a message and store it. The problem is that when I position myself in the editor the screen is cut showing only half of the editor. What could be happening? Could you help me?. Thank you very much for your help.

[image]

Here my code:

```
</TabbedPage>  
<ContentPage>
    ....
</ContentPage>  
<ContentPage>
    ....
</ContentPage>
<ContentPage x:Name="MessagesContentPage" Title="Messages" >
    <Grid BindingContext="{Binding MessageViewModel}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="Start">
            <ScrollView>
                <ListView
                     x:Name="OpportunityMessagesListView"
                     SeparatorVisibility="Default"
                     IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}" 
                     SelectionMode="None" >
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate >
                            <ViewCell >
                                <ViewCell.ContextActions>

                                    <MenuItem x:Name="MenuItemDeleteMessage" Clicked="MenuItemDeleteMessage_Clicked" Text="Eliminar" IsDestructive="True"  CommandParameter="{Binding Id}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsMenuEnabled}">
                                        <!--<MenuItem.IconImageSource>
                                            <FontImageSource Glyph="Rechazar"  FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}" Color="#e82424" />
                                        </MenuItem.IconImageSource>-->
                                    </MenuItem>
                                </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                                <Grid  x:Name="Item" Padding="3" >
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0"   Text="{Binding Message}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  LineBreakMode="CharacterWrap"/>
                                    <Label  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding CreationTime, StringFormat='{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}'}" TextColor="LightGray" BackgroundColor="Transparent" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </ScrollView>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" VerticalOptions="End"  Padding="3" Margin="3">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="8*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <customControl:ExtendedEditor x:Name="MessageExtendedEditor"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" AutoSize="TextChanges"   Placeholder="Esccriba información de seguimiento" />
            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="SaveMessageButton" Clicked="SaveMessageButton_Clicked"  FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}" Text="&#xf35a;" HeightRequest="57" VerticalOptions="End" FontSize="27" BackgroundColor="Transparent" BorderColor="Transparent" TextColor="#5694ff" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: You can try using a custom keyboard renderer to listen to the keyboard and set a margin on your control when it appears. This article shows you how, make sure you test it in Landscape as well if your app supports rotation: https://xamgirl.com/adjusting-elements-when-keyboard-shows-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: Thanks for you help, but this don´t work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a suggestion, considering that we are talking about Xamarin Forms it's better to explain if you have this issue just on Android, iOS or both (or UWP in case).

Anyway, I think that at the following link you can find all the help that you need

https://xamarinhelp.com/accommodate-on-screen-keyboard-xamarin-forms/

Let me know if it solve your problems. In case it won't solve your problem I think it is better if you explain the problem in a more detailed way.

Comment: I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54310837/8564782